# CPAN : Can't install Net/Pcap.pm

Tags: perl, cpan, libpcap

On Linux Xubuntu 14.04.3 (3.19.0-25 generic).

```
cpan > install Net::Pcap
...
CPAN.pm : Building S/SA/SAPER/Net-Pcap-0.17.tar.gz
looking for -lpcap... no
You appear to lack the pcap(3) library
...
```

Then I tried this

```
$ cd /home/user/.cpan/build/Net-Pcap-0.17-hash
$ perl Makefile.PL INC=-I/usr/include/pcap LIBS='-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcap.so -lpcap'
looking for -lpcap... no
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 You appear to lack the pcap(3) library. 

 If it is installed in a non-standard location, please try setting the LIBS 
 and INC values on the command line.

 Or get the sources and install the pcap library from http://www.tcpdump.org/

 If you install the pcap library using a system package, make sure to also 
 install the corresponding -devel package, which contains the C headers needed to compile this module. 
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

To complete the question here is the libs

```
# dpkg -L libpcap0.8-dev
...
/usr/include/pcap-bpf.h
/usr/include/pcap
/usr/include/pcap/usb.h
/usr/include/pcap/namedb.h
/usr/include/pcap/bpf.h
/usr/include/pcap/pcap.h
/usr/include/pcap/bluetooth.h
/usr/include/pcap/sll.h
/usr/include/pcap/ipnet.h
/usr/include/pcap/vlan.h
/usr/include/pcap.h
/usr/include/pcap-namedb.h
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcap.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcap.so
...
```

Please note that wireshark runs fine in this clean VM.

So what's wrong ? Is the package deprecated ?

Comment: Why not simply use libnet-pcap-perl which is available from the repositories?

Comment: Totally miss this package ; exactly what I needed, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Steffen Ullrich has suggested, I solve my problem with libnet-pcap-perl.